# set color fonts inside xml file

Tags: xml, html

I have a chat site, and it has an Language.xml file where I can edit the language and modify the predefined messages.

I want to change the color of some of the messages, but I am not having any success, can someone take a look

Here is the Original code

```
<LANG_WELCOME_USER value="Welcome %USER to %ROMENAME</LANG_WELCOME_USER>
```

I have tried the following by adding some colors to the text, but its not woking

```
<LANG_WELCOME_USER value="<font color="#FF0000">"Welcome</font>  <font color="#008000">To</font> <font color="#000080">My Chat </font>"</LANG_WELCOME_USER>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are putting double quotes inside of double quotes.  try this:

```
<LANG_WELCOME_USER value="&lt;font color='#FF0000'&gt;Welcome&lt;/font&gt;  &lt;font color='#008000'&gt;To&lt;/font&gt; &lt;font color='#000080'&gt;My Chat &lt;/font&gt;"></LANG_WELCOME_USER>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and it didnt help, I am posting the server log here, line 332 is where our code goes ------------------------------------------------------------‌​------- 
`org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 332: Use "&lt;" for "<" in attribute values. 2017-08-18 08:57:50,010 AM GMT+00:00 ERROR - get language configuration error: org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 332 of document file:/var/www/html/server/etc/groups/default/lang/language_e‌​n.xml: Use "&lt;" for "<" in attribute values. –`

Comment: Hmmm... you probably calling some kind of parser that does not escape carat tags nested in quotes. Try the revised snippet above and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the above code worked perfectly fine